# Showing that for some group it is abelian iff $x • (y • x ^{−1} ) = y$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, abelian-groups

I have to show that for some group it is abelian iff $x • (y • x^{−1}) = y$.
This is what I did:
Starting with the given statement $x • (y • x^{−1}) = y$ which implies $x • (y • x^{−1}) • x= y  • x$. Since it is a group associativity can be used giving $(x • y) • (x^{−1} • x) = y  • x$ implying $x • y = y  • x$. So since the group commutes it can be implied to be abelian.
Is this sufficient? Thank you

Comment: If this is assumed to hold for all x and y, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is not. All you did was to prove that *if* that condition holds, *then* the group is Abelian. But you also have to prove it in the other direction. That is not difficult, though: if the group is Abelian, then$$x\bullet(y\bullet x^{-1})=x\bullet(x^{-1}\bullet y)=(x\bullet x^{-1})\bullet y=y.$$

Comment: To clarify the answer: you stated at the top of the question that you have to show that a group is abelian if and only if the equation holds. This means that you have to show that this is necessary and sufficient. At the bottom of the question you pose the question "is this sufficient?" The answer is yes if you ask if this proves sufficiency. The answer is no if you ask if this is sufficient to solve your task, because your task is to show sufficiency and necessity.

Comment: @NeitherNor yes I agree in hindsight this was ambiguously worded

Answer (score 2):

This trivially follows from the following:

$$\begin{align}
x \bullet (y \bullet x^{-1}) = y &\iff (x \bullet y) \bullet x^{-1}= y \\
&\iff ((x \bullet y) \bullet x^{-1})\bullet x =y \bullet x\\
&\iff (x \bullet y) \bullet (x^{-1} \bullet x) = y \bullet x\\
&\iff (x \bullet y) \bullet 1 = y \bullet x\\
&\iff x \bullet y = y \bullet x.
\end{align}$$

Here I denoted the neutral element of the group with $1$. Try to understand why each equivalence holds (good exercise!).